# How to rename the key of a Json after fetching it in xslt

Tags: json, xpath, xslt, xslt-3.0

I want to rename the key value of a Json file in xslt after fetching it in output Json. For Example below mentioned Json File suppose I am fetching the 1st index value and in that I want to rename the field name
"age" to "membersAge" in output Json file.

My Json file is as below:-

**Json**

```
{
  "squadName": "Super hero squad",
  "homeTown": "Metro City",
  "formed": 2016,
  "secretBase": "Super tower",
  "active": true,
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "age": 29,
      "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes",
      "powers": ["Radiation resistance", "Turning tiny", "Radiation blast"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Madame Uppercut",
      "age": 39,
      "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
      "powers": [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said you in your comment, there a functions for maps (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/) to set (`map:put`) properties and to remove them (`map:remove') e.g.

```
let $m1 := ?members?1  
return $m1 =>map:put('membersAge', $m1?age) => map:remove('age')
```

so in the context of XSLT 3.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match=".">
      <xsl:sequence
        select="let $m1 := ?members?1  
                return $m1 => map:put('membersAge', $m1?age) => map:remove('age')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As for your comment to change the `age` property of each item in `members`, you can use `?*` to select all items in array, then use the `!` operator to apply the expression shown above and wrap into `array { }` to construct the new array e.g.

```
. => map:put('members',  array { ?members?* !  (map:put(., 'membersAge', ?age) => map:remove('age')) })
```

In the context of [XSLT 3](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Amap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Fmap%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22json%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20select%3D%22.%20%3D%3E%20map%3Aput%28%27members%27%2C%20%20array%20%7B%20%3Fmembers%3F*%20%21%20%20%28map%3Aput%28.%2C%20%27membersAge%27%2C%20%3Fage%29%20%3D%3E%20map%3Aremove%28%27age%27%29%29%20%7D%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22squadName%22%3A%20%22Super%20hero%20squad%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22homeTown%22%3A%20%22Metro%20City%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22formed%22%3A%202016%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22secretBase%22%3A%20%22Super%20tower%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22active%22%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22members%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Molecule%20Man%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2029%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22secretIdentity%22%3A%20%22Dan%20Jukes%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22powers%22%3A%20%5B%22Radiation%20resistance%22%2C%20%22Turning%20tiny%22%2C%20%22Radiation%20blast%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Madame%20Uppercut%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2039%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22secretIdentity%22%3A%20%22Jane%20Wilson%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22powers%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Million%20tonne%20punch%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Damage%20resistance%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Superhuman%20reflexes%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A&input-type=JSON):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match=".">
      <xsl:sequence
        select=". => map:put('members',  array { ?members?* !  (map:put(., 'membersAge', ?age) => map:remove('age')) })"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. It worked for me. I tried the same approach (by removing the specified index i.e. <xsl:sequence  select="let $m1 := ?members
                return $m1 => map:put('membersAge', $m1?age) => map:remove('age')"/>) for renaming the "age" field for both of the indexes of "members" array. But it didn't work. Please suggest.

Comment: Please don't try to cram supplementary questions into comments. It's much better to raise a new question.